# Add fex checkbox in ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can I create Column in ASPxGridView which contain 3 checkbox in one cell? Can you write example?
how this is do programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [DevExpress GridView documentation](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Templates/Template.aspx), you can use the `DataItemTemplate` syntax to do the following:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server"
                 Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="YourNameHere">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: But how this is do programmatically?